# Bootstrap 3 Example Code for Modal Window Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

This question is so simple as to be embarrassing. As a test of something I copied the code from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals directly into a page that only carries a basic page setup, and yet it doesn't work. Which means I'm doing something extremely stupid. Here's my entire page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

        <!-- Website Title & Description for Search Engine purposes -->
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">

        <!-- Mobile viewport optimized -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="includes/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="includes/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="includes/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Include Modernizr in the head, before any other Javascript -->
        <script src="includes/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>
...more buttons...

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    <!-- All Javascript at the bottom of the page for faster page loading -->

    <!-- First try for the online version of jQuery-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- If no online access, fallback to our hardcoded version of jQuery -->
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="includes/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="includes/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script src="includes/js/script.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
</script>   


</body>
</html>
```

Yet when I hit the button, the modal is launched but instead of "New Message to @mdo" like you get on their website, I get "New Message to undefined". What am I missing?

Comment: your code is working fine for me.

Comment: Works fine for me, too, here the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/HyLVxGU0qkvq16uohrPK?p=preview

Comment: Here's the link to the page:http://www.ride4wheel.com/test_site/modal.html   Can you go there and see if it works? It doesn't for me. This makes no sense.

Comment: There is an error in console. Remove in script.js the <script> & </script>

Comment: and remove the code from footer of modal.html

Comment: Okay, I did those things (which did indeed take care of some stupid mistakes) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Works fine... Wich browser do you use?

Comment: if you use IE put this in the head after description: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all it's not embarrassing, we were are there. second of all your code looks good to me. the only thing that got me is this line :

```html
<script src="includes/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

does this directory exist? because if you copy this from website it may be referring to files stored in server. try to include `bootstrap.js` yourself. same thing for the css file

Comment: It does exist. It seems like the only thing not working is the javascript. I have other pages using the same layout and basic page structure that has plenty of php and all of the bootstrap capability. It is just this one function that I can't get to work. Even though the code works, it just doesn't work on my page.

Comment: I  think that my problem is with the line:  var recipient = button.data('whatever')   : in the script. recipient is undefined despite my script running properly, and I truly do not understand this syntax. I only know it is right because it is in the example that I find everywhere. Can someone explain button.data('whatever')?

Answer (score 0):

```
     var recipient = button.data('whatever')
```

`button.data('whatever')` is undefined

Comment: Where are you getting the button.data('whatever') is undefined? It is defined in this line: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>

Answer (score 0):

Oh holy cow. The problem was (obviously) never with the code. It is with the version of either JQuery or Bootstrap that I have loaded. When I replaced my local copies with links to the source, the problem went away. I'm glad I found this problem, or it would pervade my entire site as I developed it. Thanks everyone for the help. I guess you have to learn the dumb stuff before you become expert.